# Why is the cleric class declared to be unpopular in a published game document?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, balance, cleric

In the Player's Handbook 2 it says:

> The divine spellcaster is the element most commonly missing from a party. Many players prefer to go for the spotlight with a fighter or wizard...

This seems to indicate that clerics are less popular than other class choices, but it isn't clear why that assessment is made.  The cleric has two good saves, heavy armor proficiency, solid spells, and the turn undead ability which can become more powerful with divine feats.

When one examines the commonly used [Tier evaluation criteria](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/38201/22566), a cleric is generally very powerful; with buffs, the cleric can be even more powerful than a warrior in combat.

**Why, then, is the divine spellcaster element most commonly missing from a party?**

Comment: Rather strangely related: [What makes clerics so strong in D&D 3.5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/33695/33707)

Comment: There is [a related post here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/33724/22566) that alludes to the unpopularity of the cleric by Brain B ... that might be a piece of the answer, or an allusion to the answer ..

Comment: I fail to see what kind of answers can be expected that are not basically opinions. The current accepted answer has all kinds of great reasons, but with absolutely no reason to think they're correct, as they are unsupported supposition.

Comment: Addendum: [tag:designer-reasons] was recently declared as a pariah-tag ( https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic ), and this question strikes me as such or opinion based. Both are no-gos.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is multi-fold reasoning behind this and it has little to do with their actual mechanics--it's more a matter of perception. If you read to the end of the second sentence you quoted from PHBII...

> Many players prefer to go for the spotlight with a fighter or wizard (or the equivalent) **rather than playing what they see as a supporting character.**

Emphasis Mine from PHBII 155

As to how this perception works, in my experience running games for players from veterans to newcomers...

## Perceived Obligation to Have One

Clerics are, as a general rule across editions, the best source of magical healing around. Thus, a typical party feels obligated to have a Cleric. This is true even into today where I see regular discussions about "Okay, we need a Cleric...who's going to play it." Even as a DM, I've had to step in and go "guys, you don't *need* a Cleric."

As a rule in dealing with human psychology, when something is required it becomes less desirable. It is a perceived loss of freedom. In D&D, it means that in the party, somebody *has* to play the Cleric...so somebody *has* to set aside the character they *wanted* to play so that the party has that necessary Cleric.

## Perception as "The Healer"

> Clerics  are  masters  of  divine  magic,  which  is
> especially  good  at  healing.

-Players Handbook 3.5E

Look at any MMORPG in the world and you can see that Healers are rare. Queue up for random dungeons in World of Warcraft as a Healer, and you can get a group practically instantaneously while all the DPSers have to sit and wait.

Because Clerics are generally the best at Healing, they are often perceived as a dedicated healer. I still run into this today when introducing new players to D&D and they recoil from the idea of playing the Cleric because they "Don't want to just stand around and heal all the time, that's boring."

And this isn't unique to new players...I've had to explicitly spell out the actual effectiveness of Clerics in roles other than Healing to veteran D&D players before they could get past their preconceptions about the class.

## Because Clerics are presented as 'Support Casters.'

AD&D 2E calls this out...

> Spells are the main tools of the Cleric, however, helping him to serve, fortify, protect, and revitalize those under his care

-AD&D2E Player's Handbook

A Fighter is a straightforward contributor...they rush to the front of the battle and engage directly with the enemy. A Wizard is a straightforward contributor, they Fireball and Meteor Swarm and lay waste to the battlefield. Yes, there are other, more subtle ways to play a Wizard, but the simple and obvious option is there.

Clerics have some directly offensive spells, but they are mostly focused on buffs and heals...and their direct offensive spells tend to be weaker than comparable offensive spells from other classes. As a result, the Cleric *appears* to be a PC Class that is focused on making other PC Classes succeed. While the truth of the matter can be quite different, that is a perception that is less than desirable for your average player. (Again: see the ratio of DPS players to Healers and Tanks in any MMORPG)

It feels good to drop big piles of dice worth of damage. It feels good to be the one going toe to toe with a dragon. These are straight-forward, clearly meaningful contributions to the party. A Support Caster's contributions aren't as plainly obvious...they prevent friends from dying, make friends hit harder, and so on. Again, this is not the only way to play a Cleric, but it is how they have largely been presented in the official material.

## Clerics are not presented in a way that makes them look Directly Powerful

A Cleric's magical ability to destroy stuff is not necessarily straight forward. As was mentioned in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33695/what-makes-clerics-so-strong-in-dd-3-5/33724#33724), it takes a greater degree of mastery and expertise (or luck) to draw out the merits of certain classes. In short: the ol' [CoDzilla](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/CoDzilla) is not an obvious solution. You don't look at the basic presentation of a Cleric in rulebook materials and immediately say "Wow, this guy is massively overpowered!" You have to sit down and think and look at the character's abilities, study their features and spells, not get intimidated by the vast array of options, and realize what they are capable of when you do things in the right way. Of course, as was mentioned in the linked question, it's entirely possible to trip over this power while playing a Cleric, or to discover it while digging into the class. But that's really not the sense you are given by the rulebook write-ups on the class. They are treated as "a caster who supports their allies."

'Tier' does not necessarily equate to popularity. It speaks of an optimized character created by someone with the willingness and focus to dig deep into a character's capabilities to bring out their best features.

As a result of all of this...

## Clerics don't feel like "The Hero" to a lot of players.

Heroes are the ones who directly fight and defeat monsters. Look at novels, legends, and film. The Hero is the mighty wielder of arcane power who levels powerful magic to destroy their foes, or the skilled swordsman who slays dragons with naught but his wits and his blade, or the crafty rogue who outsmarts his foes and then destroys them. You don't find support casters as the main characters of these stories.

If there is a Healer, they're basically an NPC who exists to patch the hero up after their "mighty duel." Support Casters exist to make the Hero strong enough to win the battle. This perception carries through into D&D for a lot of players (including many that I have introduced to the game). They are playing D&D to be a Hero...not the NPC that helps the Hero.

The designers were clearly aware of this, and were acknowledging that is the prime reason that a party may lack a divine caster. The way a Cleric is presented tends to breed a perception that they are this 'Supporting Character.'

Comment: Nice effort, I've been digging around for some old stuff and may offer an alternate but similar answer.

Comment: There was an interesting AD&D 2e era attempt to show the cleric as a hero main character in Salvatore’s *Cleric Quintet*. I recall it being quite good and very unusual, and yet that very fact highlighted how hard it is to get people to see clerics as protagonists. And unlike Drizzt, Cadderly failed to inspire a generation of D&D players to create copy-cat hero priests…

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I read all five, and I concur with your assessment.  While the series dragged a little bit, it did a lot to help flesh out "cleric" as a character.

Comment: “As a result, the Cleric appears to be a PC Class that is focused on making other PC Classes succeed,” is simply untrue, considering how many phenomenal self-only buffs are on the cleric spell list. It might be a *perception* but you seem to be presenting it as a fact.

Comment: Similarly, “A Cleric's magical ability to destroy stuff is not straight forward. As was mentioned in this answer, it takes a significant degree of mastery and expertise to draw out the merits of certain classes,” let’s not overstate that. One of the [other answers to that question you link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/51501/4563) describes running into the cleric’s awesome power quite naively. What is obvious to you may not be obvious to someone else, and what is un-obvious to you may seem obvious to someone else—or, obvious a or not, a new player can still stumble upon it.

Comment: In short, your last three sections really depend on perceiving the cleric a certain way. If you want to build a straight-up solo melee damage dealer, cleric is one the *best classes in the game* for that, and can very easily be that character. It’s more an issue of the cleric not being presented that way, or players not perceiving it that way regardless of its presentation, than it has anything to do with the actual abilities of the cleric class.

Comment: @KRyan That is why I used the term "Appears." As in, "Appears to players who don't know better." Perhaps that wasn't clear in how I phrased it...but if I was stating it as a fact, I wouldn't have used a qualifying term. As for your second comment...you can *stumble* over the awesome that is a cleric...which means it wasn't obvious. You had to stumble upon it in order to realize it was there. You can glance at a Wizard and go 'holy crap, that dude can level a city.' But a Cleric's power is not something an average player will notice just looking at the class.

Comment: @guildsbounty That’s my point—you *don’t* use “appears” or similar terms in many of your statements in the back half of the answer. You state that clerics “are” support, as opposed to having a “perception” as healers. You assert that new players don’t recognize the potential of the cleric class, when we have counter-factual evidence that, sometimes, they do.  This answer starts out very good by emphasizing how much of these perceptions are wrong, but then slides into asserting a lot of your own perceptions are actually true, which they are equally just your perception.

Comment: @KRyan Okay, I can put some effort into tidying up the answer and clarifying...but I opened the entire thing emphasizing that this entire answer was about Perception. Not Mechanics. That was my opening sentence. I will go through the answer and tidy that up as it was apparently not clear.

Comment: @guildsbounty [my link under the question to Brian's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/33724/22566) might have some useful nuggets for your ... and I have a couple of Dragon Mag article excerpts that might be useful.